# Change resolution when exporting map canvas as image with python

Tags: pyqgis, export, qgsmapcanvas

I want to create a georeference png of the map canvas in QGIS using Python with:

```
mapCanvas().saveAsImage('filename.png')
```

I want to be able to change the resolution from the default of 96 dpi.

Is there a way to adjust this using the Python editor within QGIS?

Answer (score 2):

I assume, you run your map render context in a standalone application. I'm not sure if you want to produce high resolution images or set only the DPI number.

If you want to produce high resolution images, you could set [`mapCanvas()mapSettings().setDevicePixelRatio(scaleFactor)`](https://qgis.org/api/qgsmapsettings_8cpp_source.html#l00256) before you call `mapCanvas().saveAsImage('FILENAME.PNG')`.  The function triggers `QgsMapSettings::updateDerived()` and calculates the [`mapUnitsPerPixel`](https://qgis.org/api/qgsmapsettings_8cpp_source.html#l00119) and the new DPI number.

```
 # line 170
 // calculate the translation and scaling parameters
 const double mapUnitsPerPixelY = mExtent.height() / myHeight;
 const double mapUnitsPerPixelX = mExtent.width() / myWidth;
 mMapUnitsPerPixel = mapUnitsPerPixelY > mapUnitsPerPixelX ? mapUnitsPerPixelY : mapUnitsPerPixelX;
 ...
 # Line 192 
 ...
 // update the scale
 mScaleCalculator.setDpi( mDpi * mDevicePixelRatio );
 mScale = mScaleCalculator.calculate( mVisibleExtent, mSize.width() );
```

I have not tested this befor because, I personally try to avoid the rendering into an image context and use a the pdf printer context instead. In the printer context you have all properties to render your map into a well defined page.  You can use `imagemagick` or `ghostscript` to create DPI correct and anti-aliased images later.

### Example code snippet from one of my projects

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtXml import *

# ---------------------------------------------------
# Constants 
# ---------------------------------------------------
SHP_DATA     = 'ogr'
QGIS_PATH    = '/usr'
PAGE_WIDTH   = 300 # mm
PAGE_HEIGHT  = 300 # mm
MAP_WIDTH    = 130
MAP_HEIGHT   = 130
MAP_LEFT     = 25
MAP_TOP      = 10
MAP_RIGHT    = MAP_LEFT + MAP_WIDTH
MAP_BOTTOM   = MAP_TOP  + MAP_HEIGHT
GAP          = 40
LEG_TOP      = MAP_TOP
LEG_LEFT     = MAP_RIGHT + GAP

# -----------------------------------------------------
# Keys for the map frame
# -----------------------------------------------------
# Label inside or outside of the map 
GRID_ANNON_INMAP  = 0
GRID_ANNON_OUTMAP = 1
GRID_ANNON_NONE   = 2

# Keys for the grid annotation side
GRID_SIDE_RIGHT   = 0
GRID_SIDE_LEFT    = 1
GRID_SIDE_BOTTOM  = 2
GRID_SIDE_TOP     = 3

# Keys for the label direction
GRID_ANNON_DIR_0    = 0
GRID_ANNON_DIR_90   = 1
GRID_ANNON_DIR_180  = 2
GRID_ANNON_DIR_270  = 3

# Keys for the axis format
GRID_ANNON_FMT_DEC = 0 # Dezimalzahlen + N, E
GRID_ANNON_FMT_DM  = 1 # D°M'N und D°M'E 
GRID_ANNON_FMT_DMS = 2 # D°M'S"N und D°M'S"E 
GRID_ANNON_FMT_DEC_NONSWE  = 3 # Ohne Dezimalzahlen
GRID_ANNON_FMT_DM_NONSWE   = 4 # D°M'

# Gridd type
GRID_FRAME_PLAIN = 0 # einfache Linie
GRID_FRAME_ZEBRA = 1 # Kästchen

# -----------------------------------------------------
# Settings for the map frame
# -----------------------------------------------------
# Schrittweite der Label 10km 
GRID_FRAME_STEP_LABX = 1/3.0
GRID_FRAME_STEP_LABY = 1/6.0

# Fonts font for the map labels
GRID_FRAME_FONT = QFont('Arial',11,0)

# Precisiion of the labels
GRID_FRAME_PRECISION = 0

# Size of the map crosses 0 if you don't want
GRID_FRAME_CROSS_SIZE = 0

# Breite des Rahmens
GRID_FRAME_WIDTH = 1

# Colors for the frame 
GRID_COLOR_LIGHT = QColor('#ffffff')
GRID_COLOR_DARK  = QColor('#040404')
 
# ---------------------------------------------------
# Create a map
# ---------------------------------------------------
# @param page - Composer page 
# @param upper - Upper border of the sheet in mm
# @param left  - Left border of the sheet in mm
# @param lower - Lower border of the sheet in mm
# @param right - Right border of the sheet in mm
# @param extent - Extent of the map info world coordinates only
# @return Map with border config (..see also GRID_FRAME_*)
# ---------------------------------------------------
def createMap(page, upper, left, lower, right, extent):
    # Karte bauen
    print "Create ma sheet:  (%d, %d) (%d, %d) [mm]" % (upper, left, lower, right)
    print "    Size UTM:  (%2.0f,%2.0f) (%2.0f, %2.0f) [m]" \
      % (extent.xMinimum(), extent.yMinimum(), \
         extent.xMaximum(), extent.yMaximum())
    cmap = QgsComposerMap(page, upper, left, lower, right)
    # Kartenabdeckung eintragen
    cmap.setNewExtent(extent)
    # Create frame and cosses ----------------------
    cmap.setGridStyle(GRID_FRAME_ZEBRA)
    # Label font 
    cmap.setGridAnnotationFont(GRID_FRAME_FONT)
    # Size of the crosses
    cmap.setCrossLength(GRID_FRAME_CROSS_SIZE)
    # Intervalabstand setzten
    cmap.grid().setCrs(tk.epsgCrs(4326))
    cmap.setGridIntervalX(GRID_FRAME_STEP_LABX)
    cmap.setGridIntervalY(GRID_FRAME_STEP_LABY)
    # Label format
    cmap.setGridAnnotationFormat(GRID_ANNON_FMT_DM_NONSWE)
    # Precision of the label format
    cmap.setGridAnnotationPrecision(GRID_FRAME_PRECISION)
    # Ausrichtung des Labels fuer die ensprechende Achse
    cmap.setGridAnnotationDirection(GRID_ANNON_DIR_90,
                                    GRID_SIDE_LEFT)
    cmap.setGridAnnotationDirection(GRID_ANNON_DIR_90,
                                    GRID_SIDE_RIGHT)
    # Label per axis Labelposition
    cmap.setGridAnnotationPosition(GRID_ANNON_OUTMAP,
                                   GRID_SIDE_TOP)
    cmap.setGridAnnotationPosition(GRID_ANNON_OUTMAP,
                                   GRID_SIDE_RIGHT)
    cmap.setGridAnnotationPosition(GRID_ANNON_OUTMAP,
                                   GRID_SIDE_LEFT)
    cmap.setGridAnnotationPosition(GRID_ANNON_OUTMAP,
                                   GRID_SIDE_BOTTOM)
    # Activate annotation
    cmap.setShowGridAnnotation(1)
    # Frame style -----------------------------
    cmap.setGridFrameStyle(GRID_FRAME_ZEBRA)
    # Frame width
    cmap.setGridFrameWidth(GRID_FRAME_WIDTH)
    # Frame color (hell & dunkel)
    cmap.setGridFrameFillColor1(GRID_COLOR_LIGHT)
    cmap.setGridFrameFillColor2(GRID_COLOR_DARK)
    # Enable frame 
    cmap.setFrameEnabled(True)
    return cmap

# ------------------------------------------------------
# Start application ...
# ------------------------------------------------------
application = QgsApplication([], True)
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(QGIS_PATH, True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()

# ------------------------------------------------------
# Service function print a page into a pdf
# ------------------------------------------------------
def writePdfFullPage(page, width, height, fileName='out.pdf'):
    print "Schreibe PDF: "+fileName
    printer = QPrinter()
    printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter.PdfFormat)
    printer.setOutputFileName(fileName)
    printer.setPaperSize(QSizeF(width, height), QPrinter.Millimeter)
    printer.setFullPage(True)
    printer.setColorMode(QPrinter.Color)
    printer.setResolution(page.printResolution())

    pdfPainter = QPainter(printer)
    paperRectMM = printer.pageRect(QPrinter.Millimeter)
    paperRectPixel = printer.pageRect(QPrinter.DevicePixel)
    page.render(pdfPainter, paperRectPixel, paperRectMM)
    pdfPainter.end()

# ------------------------------------------------------
# Calculate the map extent
# ------------------------------------------------------
def calcMapExt(lyr, offs=0.01):
    result = lyr.extent()
    print "Map extent:", result.xMinimum(), result.yMinimum(), result.xMaximum(), result.yMaximum()
    result.setXMinimum(result.xMinimum()-offs)
    result.setYMinimum(result.yMinimum()-offs)
    result.setXMaximum(result.xMaximum()+offs)
    result.setYMaximum(result.yMaximum()+offs)
    print "Map extent:", result.xMinimum(), result.yMinimum(), result.xMaximum(), result.yMaximum()
    return result;

# ---------------------------------------------------
# Open a vector layer  
# ---------------------------------------------------
def openVectorLayer(uri, name):
    print "Open layer: %s " % (name)  
    layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(),name,SHP_DATA)
    if not layer.isValid():
          msg  = "Cannot open layer  '"+name+"'\n"
          msg += "File:     "+uri+"\n"
          msg += "Filter:   "+where+"\n"
          raise ValueError(msg)
    print "    %d Object(s)" % (layer.featureCount())  
    return layer

# ----------------------------------------------
# Create the legend
# ----------------------------------------------
def createLegend (page, layers,  x, y, title, \
                  titleFont = QFont('Arial',12,2), \
                  groupFont = QFont('Arial',11,1), 
                  itemFont  = QFont('Arial',10,1) ):
    print "Create legend: %s %d %d " % (title, x, y)
    cleg = QgsComposerLegend(page)
    cleg.setTitle(title)
    cleg.rstyle(QgsComposerLegendStyle.Symbol).setMargin(QgsComposerLegendStyle.Top, 1)
    cleg.setStyleFont(QgsComposerLegendStyle.Title, titleFont)
    cleg.setStyleFont(QgsComposerLegendStyle.Subgroup, groupFont)
    cleg.setStyleFont(QgsComposerLegendStyle.SymbolLabel, itemFont)
    cleg.setX(x)
    cleg.setY(y)
    cleg.model().setLayerSet(layers)
    return cleg

# ---------------------------------------------------
# Read some layers and add a renderer
# ---------------------------------------------------
# Region of interest 
lyrRoi     = openVectorLayer('roi.shp','roi')
symRoi = QgsSimpleLineSymbolLayerV2()
symRoi.setColor(QColor('#dd4433'))
symRoi.setWidth(1)
lyrRoi.rendererV2().symbols()[0].changeSymbolLayer(0, symRoi)

# Special protection area
lyrSPA = openVectorLayer('SPA.shp','SPA')
symSPAa = QgsSimpleLineSymbolLayerV2()
colSPA = QColor('#aaaaaa');
symSPAa.setColor(colSPA)
symSPAa.setWidth(0.5)
symSPAb = QgsLinePatternFillSymbolLayer()
symSPAb.setColor(colSPA)
symSPAb.setLineWidth(0.5)
symSPAb.setLineAngle(45.0)
symSPAb.setDistance(1.5);
lyrSPA.rendererV2().symbols()[0].changeSymbolLayer(0, symSPAa)
lyrSPA.rendererV2().symbols()[0].appendSymbolLayer(symSPAb)

# -------------------------------------------
# Open the render engine 
# -------------------------------------------
renderer = QgsMapRenderer()
mapCrs   = tk.epsgCrs(3395)
renderer.setDestinationCrs(mapCrs)
renderer.setProjectionsEnabled(True)

mapset = []

mapset.append(lyrRoi.id())
mapset.append(lyrContent.id())
...
renderer.setLayerSet(mapset)
mapExtent  = calcMapExt(lyrRoi);
mapTrfm    = QgsCoordinateTransform(lyrRoi.crs(), mapCrs)
mapExtent  = mapTrfm.transform(mapExtent)
renderer.setExtent(mapExtent)

# --------------------------------------------------
# Declare a page and store the PDF
# --------------------------------------------------   
page = QgsComposition(renderer)
page.setPlotStyle(QgsComposition.Print)

# Create the map...
cmap= createMap(page, MAP_LEFT, MAP_TOP, \
               MAP_RIGHT, MAP_BOTTOM, mapExtent)

...
# Legende
cleg = createLegend( page, mapset, \
                    LEG_LEFT, LEG_TOP, \
                    '')

writePdfFullPage(page,PAGE_WIDTH, PAGE_HEIGHT, \
 fileName='example.pdf')

print "OK."
QgsApplication.exitQgis()

# EOF
```

Comment: I am using it in QGIS python script editor. I am a little confused how to use  the set device pixel command. I tested like this using both 1 and 100 and it had no effect on the output image: iface.mapCanvas().mapSettings().setDevicePixelRatio(1);
iface.mapCanvas().saveAsImage('FILENAME.PNG').

Comment: OK have , as mentioned, used the code above only in a QGIS stand alone context. What is the code base to execute the task within QGIS?